# How to collect/extract data from a previously running website that has become a security issue?

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, webserver

I have a project that has been assigned to me that involves recovering/extracting data from a previously running website/data form.  The website had not been maintained for quite some time and since been deactivated from public use.  I have been given the .htm , .asp, and .js files that were used to construct the originally website, but I am unfamiliar with how I should go about finding the previously collected data.

Once I do have the location of the data how would I go about extracting the information for review?  The information needs to be collected and reviewed in order to see the value/validity of what had been collected for many years.

The only information I have gathered so far is that the website is Windows OS Server working with ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'd even bother with the code. Once you have a database location, start looking at fields. If you start seeing fields that involve sensitive information (field name includes `ssn`, `dob`, `maiden` (name), etc), you'll have a good idea of what needs to be sanitized.

God help you if there's credit card info in there.

As far as viewing the data, that's where code may come in handy -- it'll tell you what type of backend was being used. If it's an access database, you can install MS Access and open up the MDB. If it was an SQL Server database, you'll need the client side tools, and a working server to talk to.

Comment: So in order to find the data collected I need the location of the database?  Luckily there was no pertinent data as far as sensitive information, more-so that of contact info for particular clients.  If the website had been disabled would be the database still be accessible?  The rest depends on Access Database VS SQL Server database then, correct?

Comment: The code will pull the data from some type of storage; you should be able to see it opening up some type of database connection to query and write data. That connection string should give you an idea of where to look. If the database is access, the location will be a file path. If the database is SQL, the connection string will include a server name (possibly localhost), a database name, and a user and password to connect with. There are other storage engine possibilities (including a comma delimited file, or another type of database engine.)

Comment: If the website is disable, there may be no way to get to the data via http, but in the case of the access database, anyone with the ability to read the server's filesystem can get at the mdb. In the case of a SQL Server, the credentials may still work, and that data could be accessible by directly connecting.